# Householder QR problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-decomposition, reflection

Can somebody give me a hint or help me to solve this problem.

Let V be a p×q matrix with orthonormal columns (p > q), and $M = I−2VV^T$ 
,  with I being the p × p identity matrix. The matrix M can be viewed as a “generalization” of a Householder matrix.

(a) Show that $||M||^2 = 1$.
(b) Compute the Frobenius norm of M

Answer (score 0):

(a) Compute $Mv$ with $v$ being a column of $V$. Compute $Mx$ for a vector $x$ orthogonal to all columns of $V$ ($x^TV=0$). Take a suitable orthonormal basis of the space to conclude.

(b) $\|M\|_F^2 = tr(M^TM)$ and take advantage of $V^TV = I_q$.